# clipShape gives unwanted padding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm wanting to add rounded corners to the top of my view while having the view stay pinned to the bottom of the view. Here is a photo to help my poor explanation.
[image: Photo screen showing padding on bottom of screen]

I'm wanting to have the bottom of the view still flush to the bottom. I've tried many different methods, even if I only round the top corners I still get the padding at the bottom. I've looked into safeAreaInset and cannot seem to make it work for me.
Below is the code for my view.

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        showNewScreen.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                            .padding(.leading)
                    })
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: { showingSheet.toggle() }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                            .padding(.trailing)
                    })
                }
                .padding(.top)
                
                VStack {
                    TextField("Type something here...", text: $visionModel.textFieldText)
                        .padding(.leading)
                        .frame(height: 55)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    Spacer()
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("Which section are you adding to?")
                            .bold()
                        
                        Picker("Which section", selection: $selected) {
                            Text(SegmentSelected.task.rawValue).tag(SegmentSelected.task)
                            
                            Text(SegmentSelected.textSectionOne.rawValue).tag(SegmentSelected.textSectionOne)
                            
                            Text(SegmentSelected.textSectionTwo.rawValue).tag(SegmentSelected.textSectionTwo)
                        }
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                        .cornerRadius(6)
                        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                        
                    }
                    //MARK: Add a pop up alert to tell user we have successfully added a new item
                    
                    if selected == .task {
                        VStack() {
                            DatePicker("", selection: $timeSelected, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                                .labelsHidden()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    Button(action: saveButtonPressed, label: {
                        Text("Save".uppercased())
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .frame(height: 55)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.2))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        
                    })
                    .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert, content: getAlert)
                }
                .padding(14)
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                    VisionView()
                        .task {
                            await visionModel.requestDataScannerAccessStatus()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous))
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the background has rounded corners, you need to apply `.ignoresSafeArea` explicitly to ignore the safe area at the bottom.

Then to hide the rounded corners at the bottom on devices that don't have screens with rounded corners (such as an iPhone 8), you can use a combination of positive padding, negative padding and y-offset around the modifier that sets the background.

Like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Top")
            Spacer()
            Text("Lots of content here")
            Spacer()
            Text("Bottom")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 25)
    .background(
        Color.blue
            .cornerRadius(25)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
    )
    .padding(.top, -25)
    .offset(y: 25)
}
```

[image: RoundedCorners]

---

*EDIT* I thought of another way to cover the rounded corners at the bottom, which is perhaps a bit cleaner. Just use an overlay over the bottom part of the background and don't give it rounded corners! This avoids the need for the positive and negative padding plus offset. Like this:

```swift
ZStack {
    // as before
}
.background(
    Color.blue
        .cornerRadius(25)
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.blue
                .frame(height: 25)
        }
)
```

Comment: Answer updated with another (and perhaps better) way to mask the rounded corners at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you!! I've updated my code, appreciate you contributing more!

Comment: @BenzyNeez in your 2nd solution why we need `.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.blue
                .frame(height: 25)
        }` ... I think it covers all `bottom` without that when we set `frame` to `infinity`

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon I still see rounded corners, even if `maxHeight: .infinity` is applied to the background. Try it on a device with square corners to see it (like an iPhone SE).